# PHP query runs even if button is not clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I have a strange problem. I have set a query to insert two names in the database. I have also used Javascript(Jquery) to run it only when the create button is clicked. But it runs evry time I reload the page...

Button:

```
<button id="button-create" type="button" style="float:right;">Create</button>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-create").click(function(){
        $('body').append('<div class="box" id="12"><div class="head">Homework<button class="button-delete" data-panelid="12" type="button" style="float:right;">Delete</button></div><div class="text">Valkommen!</div></div>').children(':last').hide().slideDown(500);
        <?php
            $query123 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post (head, content) VALUES       ('John', 'Doe')");
            $query123->execute();
        ?>
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not calling the query in a function or conditional statement so it *will* execute every time you load the page. You should try to perform this with AJAX.

Comment: PHP is run *on the server* before the page is served to the client.  *Then*, when the browser receives the results of the PHP script's execution, it will parse/execute any client-side Javascript code.

Comment: PHP is run server side before the page is served to the client.  You'll need to do an ajax call if you only want it executed on button click

Answer (score 0):

It is because your PHP script is executed every time your Server, for example Apache, serves that page or in trivial terms, the user reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it does that is because it's PHP-code. When rendering the PHP-file, the server will execute ALL of the PHP. So when you run the page, it will run that php code before it goes to the browser...

All the PHP will be executed and only the **output** from the PHP will be sent to the browser. So your database execute will be executed already.

PHP code => Running on server

JS code => Running in browser

**There is no way they can communicate directly.**

If you want to do something like this, you need an ajax call to a page that will execute the SQL Query.

I would recommend to watch this introduction to the difference between PHP and Javascript: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJJvK3Fre0I